# Django: Module "django.template.loaders.filesystem" does not define a "Loader" callable template source loader

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I created a pretty basic Django project using `django-admin` and I'm now running into the following problem when I try to view my admin application in the browser while running with `manage.py runserver`:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/
Module "django.template.loaders.filesystem" does not define a "Loader" callable template source loader
```

For a reference, here's my `settings.py` file:

```
# Django settings for mine project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/tmp/mine.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'
DATABASE_NAME = '/tmp/mine.db'
DATABASE_USER = ''
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
DATABASE_HOST = ''

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mine.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    #'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'mine.main',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

I had to comment out a bunch of stuff as you can see and I had to use a different way of defining my database than the one that they provided. I had other errors being thrown if I left some of the other items in there. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) you can see correct loader package-paths. It appears to me, you should use them.

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader
```

Comment: additionally: `django.template.loaders.eggs.load_template_source`. thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix would be to upgrade the Django installation.

That `settings.py` file appears to have been created for a more recent version of Django than what is currently installed.

`Loader` was added to `django.template.loaders.filesystem` in [this revision](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py?rev=11862).

Answer (score -4):

It seems that you may want to comment out one of the DB settings as below, as the second set of database connection settings seems redundant:

```
    DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': '/tmp/mine.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
       }
    }

   #DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'
   #DATABASE_NAME = '/tmp/mine.db'
   #DATABASE_USER = ''
   #DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
   #DATABASE_HOST = ''
```